# Bit Shifting - Why is this code using 24, 16, and 8 right shift?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I am looking at this java code and trying to understand it.  I understand everything about it except the bit shifting part.

I know the code below that uses bit shifting is building some values to fill up in the byte[] but I dont know why specifically it uses right shift and why for 24, then 16, then 8 bits?  Where and why are these values picked and not some other values?

```
private void Send(NetSocket out, int MsgID, byte MsgSeq, char MsgLetter, String data) 
{
    int msglen = data.length() + 2; 
    byte[] msg = new byte[msglen + 8];
    byte[] md = data.getBytes();
    msg[0] = (byte) (msglen >> 24);
    msg[1] = (byte) (msglen >> 16);
    msg[2] = (byte) (msglen >> 8);
    msg[3] = (byte) (msglen);
    msg[4] = (byte) (MsgID >> 24);
    msg[5] = (byte) (MsgID >> 16);
    msg[6] = (byte) (MsgID >> 8);
    msg[7] = (byte) (MsgID);
    msg[8] = (byte) MsgLetter;
    msg[9] = MsgSeq;
    System.arraycopy(md, 0, msg, 10, msglen - 2);

    // send
}
```

Comment: Because a byte is 8 bits

Comment: It's manually doing a big-endian encoding of a 32-bit integer as 4 bytes. A 32-bit integer can be divided into four bytes of 8 bits each, starting at the bit offsets 0, 8, 16, and 24.

Comment: @DanielPryden sure but that is not question I have.  I know 32 bit integer has 4 x 8 length

Comment: @cd491415: Your question specifically says "why are these values picked and not some other values?" The answer is: because a byte has 8 bits, and those numbers are multiples of 8. Or am I misunderstanding your question entirely?

Comment: @cd491415 and if you right-shift by 32, then *logically* you'd get all zeros (assuming unsigned)... in reality, IIRC if you right-shift by 32 it does *nothing at all* (on many frameworks, the right-shift argument is masked with 31, i.e. only 5 bits of it are used)

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: method names and parameters begin with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 32 bit integer, you can treat it as four 8-bit integers:

```
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01
\---------------------/ \---------------------/ \---------------------/ \------------------/
  bits 24-31 (8 bits)     bits 16-23 (8 bits)      bits 8-15 (8 bits)     bits 0-7 (8 bits)
```

*Big-endian* encoding is where you send the most-significant byte first, so you want bits 24-31 in the first byte, bits 16-23 in the second byte, and so forth. The standard byte order for network communications is big-endian. (*Little-endian* is the other way around, and is commonly used for in-memory storage on x86 and some other platforms.)

If you cast an integer to a byte, the *most significant* bits are thrown away.

```
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01
\---------------------/ \---------------------/ \---------------------/ \------------------/
  bits 24-31 (8 bits)     bits 16-23 (8 bits)      bits 8-15 (8 bits)     bits 0-7 (8 bits)


             cast to (byte)
                                                                        07 06 05 04 03 02 01
                                                                        \------------------/
                                                                          bits 0-7 (8 bits)
```

If you *shift right*, you move the bits over, so that you can cast to `(byte)` and successively get the other parts of the 32-bit integer:

```
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01
\---------------------/ \---------------------/ \---------------------/ \------------------/
  bits 24-31 (8 bits)     bits 16-23 (8 bits)      bits 8-15 (8 bits)     bits 0-7 (8 bits)
          |
          \---------------------------- >> 24 -----------------------------------\
                                                                                 |
                                                                        07 06 05 04 03 02 01
                                                                        \------------------/
                                                                        previously bits 24-31
                                                                        now bits 0-7 (8 bits)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply packing the 4 bytes of a 32-bit integer into 4 successive bytes, taking care to use a specific endianness (big-endian in this case). It is simply saying:

```
// put the "biggest" 8 bits into the first byte,
// by right shifting the value 24 bits
msg[0] = (byte) (msglen >> 24);
```

right shifting a 32-bit integer 24 bits means you are left with the 8 most significant bits in the *least* significant 8 places, ready to pack into a `byte`. The next 3 lines deal with the next 8 bits (right-shift 16), then the next (right-shift 8), etc.

Casting to a `byte` simply *discards* everything except the least significant 8 bits, so after each shift (or lack of a shift in the final one), we take one quarter of the 32 bits.

So again: this simply implements a big-endian length prefix of a frame. The receiving code will reverse this by left-shifting and or-ing, to rebuild the length from the first 4 bytes.