# What is the purpose of '<<8 <<16 <<24' in this C++ code snippet for reading binary files?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I don't understand how these rows works, in particularly the expression << 8, << 16, << 24

```
while (1) {
    int32_t num = 0;
    num += is.get();
    num += is.get() << 8;
    num += is.get() << 16;
    num += is.get() << 24;
    if (!is) {
        break;
    }
    v.push_back(num);
}
```

I have a 32-bit binary file (is) and need to read and write a 32-bit txt file, my professor solve the exercise, but i don't understand this rows. I know that this operator `<<` is the left shift, but I don't understand why I need to do this `<<8 <<16 <<24`

The file contains numbers in binary, there are also negative numbers like -98 in binary

Comment: As posted that simply doesn't compile. If you mean `<<`, that's a binary left shift operation. You can lookup for those in the documentation.

Comment: Read about [arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) specifically bit shifts. Then you need to remember about bytes, groups of 8 bits and connect that to the numbers 8,16,24

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bit Shifting - Why is this code using 24, 16, and 8 right shift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520664/bit-shifting-why-is-this-code-using-24-16-and-8-right-shift)

Comment: The code is converting four bytes into an integer. The left shift operations multiply the byte values. It's just like you know that `1234` is one thousand, two hundred and thirty four. You read `1` and you shift it to `1000`, you read `2` and you shift it to `200`. It's the same here only in binary not decimal. Also note that the bytes are read backwards compared to how we read decimal numbers. The lowest byte is first, not last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post a question, you need to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The call `cin.get()` is reading a single byte at a time from the file. In order to construct a 32-bit integer from each group of four bytes, it shifts the values by 0, 8, 16, and 24 bits as it adds them to the result. It could have also used `|=` to do a bitwise or to construct the result.

The code assumes that the binary data is in [`little endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) format. Also, I think it will ignore the last integer because it breaks out of the loop before adding it to the `std::vector`.

Here is what I think would be a correct loop (assuming that the input stream `is` is in binary mode):

```cpp
void read_binary_bytes(std::stream& is, std::vector<int32_t>& v) {
    while (is) {
        int32_t num = 0;
        num += is.get();
        num += (is.get() << 8);
        num += (is.get() << 16);
        num += (is.get() << 24);
        if (is)
            v.push_back(num);
    }
}
```